Existence of semi-group with local but not global identity
I was wondering if there exists a semi-group in which some elements have a two-sided identity, while some others do not (they either have one-sided identities or no identities at all).
I came up with the 2-membered set $\{a,b\}$ with the binary operation defined as below, which seems to be an associative binary operator:
$$a^2 = a, \quad b^2 = b, \quad ab = a, \quad ba = b$$
I do not know how to make sure this operator is associative (therefore making the structure a semi-group); however, assuming that this is indeed a semi-group fulfilling the condition I mentioned at the beginning of the post, are there any other semi-groups with a similar property in which the "local identities" are not just the elements being their own identities?

Note that this always gives $pqr=p$ however it is bracketed - the operation maps the product to the first factor.

Note the semigroup of square matrices of order $2$ whose second row is zero.

Idempotents are local identities to themselves.

Your example is a left-zero semigroup, i.e., a semigroup defined by the identity $xy=x$. This is trivially associative (see the first comment), and each element is itself a semigroup (indeed, a group!) having that element as the identity. It's rather trivial, but it might work for your proposes.

A subgroup of a semigroup is a subsemigroup that is a group.  Its identity is a local one in general.
An example can be found here.
Any semigroup with at least two subgroups that do not share an identity should suffice.

Maybe more can be added as to how these properties help solve the question?

Done, @TymaGaidash.

If I have understood what you said correctly, then any proper semigroup which has a non-trivial subgroup should satisfy the condition. Is this correct?

Any semigroup with two subgroups that do not share an identity should suffice, @MehdiRejali.

Given any idempotent $e \in S$, one could consider the subset of those $x \in S$ for which there exists $y \in S$ for which $xy=yx=e$ and $xyx=x$ and $yxy=y$. This is a subgroup with identity $e$, and there is one such subgroup for each idempotent.

Here's another approach than the one with subgroups of the semigroup.
A very easy way to come up with semigroups (which might not have a global neutral element) having many different sub-semigroups with different neutral elements is start with a finite semilattice $(S,\wedge)$ (here, I'm considering $a\wedge b$ to be the greatest lower bound of $a$ and $b$).
Each chain contained in $S$ is finite, and as such it has a greatest element, which is the neutral element of the sub-semigroup which is that chain.
